# How to send input to a useMutation hook from react query on form submit?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, formik, react-query

I'm trying to invoke a mutation on form submit which is used to log the user in, my function that I'm trying to invoke is this :

```
export const login = async (email : string , password : string) => {
  
  const response = await  axios.post(`${BASE_URL}/users/login` , {"user":{email:email, password:password}});

  return response.data;

}
```

I'm trying to invoke it using this code :

```
  const { mutate, isLoading , error} = useMutation(variables => login(variables.email , variables.password))
```

My on submit for the form looks like this :

```
  onSubmit={(values) => {
    console.log(values);
    mutate({email : values.email , password:values.password});
  }}
```

But I'm getting multiple errors doing this, what's the correct way to do it?

the errors are :
Property 'email' does not exist on type 'void'.

Property 'password' does not exist on type 'void'.

Argument of type '{ email: string; password: string; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'void'.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't have `variables` typed in your mutationFn, so they are inferred to `void`.

It is best to directly type annotate the parameters that get into the mutationFn:

```
const { mutate, isLoading , error} = useMutation(
  (variables: { email: string; password: string}) => login(variables.email , variables.password)
)
```

[see this typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=15&ssc=2&pln=13&pc=1#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAbzgVwM4FMCyyYEMbAQB2cAvnAGZQQhwDkAAnkangMYDWA9FOrmzAC0AR2TooATzpw4AKFCRYcXAA9CqStVp1V6urLbFWcAEIBBAMoBRAPoBVAEoAZOAF44AIg%20zZ6FYvhDFngAGwgAc2ASd1xUCSI2OAAKdBBcYBC4AC44Vigo8LgAGjgwWNQAd2gAE2zcmHyicIBKNwA%20RFkZLrgg415USBZ0N2UK9PhlNQhUADpIViSAAwASBHNre2dSLjRxVC4wyKIl4sQPPagPLIRU9JCsu4ySstRKmqzX96hq0lJmgDcPhkvBgyCgJAGQwws2q%20FwQNkpB6Mm6fXgSBAOHw6BKwFQTgguGqBTO4moUHI7j22DwBGISR6SQAbrh8rgAEYhdCoHJIJ4PeqNcIA0rlKo-HJ5Ar-dpwI5RFls4Cc7lzAVnVnsrk8%20bimrNWSGoA)

All of this works a lot better if your `login` function already takes an object, because then you can just pass `login` as the mutationFn itself:

```
export const login = async ({email, password }: { email: string; password: string}) => {
  
  const response = await  axios.post(`${BASE_URL}/users/login` , {"user":{email:email, password:password}});

  return response.data;

}
      
const { mutate, isLoading , error} = useMutation(login)
```

[see this typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAbzgVwM4FMCyyYEMbAQB2cAvnAGZQQhwDkAAnkangMYDWA9FOrmzAC0AR2TooATzpw4AKFCRYcXAA9CqStVp1V6urLbFWcAEIBBAMoBRAPoBVAEoAZOAF44AIg%20zZ6FYvhDFngAGwgAc2ASd1xUCSI2OAAKBHQQXGAQgBo4MFjUAHdoABMyAC5EODSMkIrWKCjwgG5c-KKoYrqYBqJw0gBKNwA%20RFkZMbgg415USBZ0N2UCjPhlNQhUADpIViSAAwASBHNre2dSLjRxVC4wyKI9uByEDyuoDzLU9Myy6sycvKoQolMqA4EdUgDJo%20GS8GDIKAkGZzDCbYr4XDQ2SkCYycZTeBIEA4fDoHLAVBOCC4YqNJ5VKDUKDkdxXbB4AjEJJ3KL9WRAA)

Of course, this assumes that you are in control of the `login` function and can shape it however you want. If that's not the case, the mapping is necessary as the `mutate` function can only take one argument.

Comment: that's very helpful and it works great , makes a lot of sense now . t